# How can I improve this bash command to get UI rendering times from ActivityManager?

Tags: regex, bash, sed, grep, activity-manager

I'm working on a sample app based on [Fire App Builder](https://github.com/amzn/fire-app-builder) and would like to programatically measure how long (in milliseconds) it takes for an `Activity` to be drawn. This information is included in the `ActivityManager` logs:

```
I/ActivityManager( 1843): Displayed com.amazon.android.calypso/com.amazon.android.tv.tenfoot.ui.activities.ContentBrowseActivity: +656ms
```

Times above one second look like this:

```
I/ActivityManager( 1843): Displayed com.amazon.android.calypso/com.amazon.android.tv.tenfoot.ui.activities.ContentBrowseActivity: +1s001ms
```

However, Android is designed such that apps can only read their own logs. As such, `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -d ActivityManager:I *:S")` won't show anything. I can read the logs using a shell command, but my regular expression isn't giving me what I want.

The following command

```
adb logcat -d ActivityManager:I *:S | sed -n 's/ContentBrowseActivity:\s+\+\([0-9].*\)ms/\1/p'
```

matches, but because `sed` doesn't support non-greedy expressions, the whole line is printed:

```
I/ActivityManager( 1843): Displayed com.amazon.android.calypso/com.amazon.android.tv.tenfoot.ui.activities.656
```

I want to get just the time. Tacking on another `grep` command gets the data:

```
adb logcat -d ActivityManager:I *:S | sed -n 's/ContentBrowseActivity:\s+\+\([0-9].*\)ms/\1/p' | grep -Po [0-9]+
```

For times above one second, I want to simply multiply the first number by 1,000 and add it to the second.

However, this is extremely hacky and also captures the number in `I/ActivityManager(####)`. Another know of a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ echo 'I/ActivityManager( 1843): Displayed com.amazon.android.calypso/com.amazon.android.tv.tenfoot.ui.activities.ContentBrowseActivity: +1s001ms' | sed -e 's/^.*: +\(.*\)ms$/\1/' -e 's/s//'
1001
```

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't seem to work for me. I tried `adb logcat -d ActivityManager:I *:S |  sed -e 's/^.*: +\(.*\)ms$/\1/' -e 's/s//'`, and it just dumps a bunch of lines from `ActivityManager`.

Comment: Just saw your updated answer. It works like a charm. Thanks so much!